# How can I change the drawer selected item on button fragment change?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I would like to know how i can change the selected item in the navigation drawer when i change fragmets with a button.

The starting fragment "Home" has buttons that change the current fragment to another. When the fragment is changed from "Home" to "Work" the selected item in the navigation drawer doesnt change from Home to Work respectively. Being a begginer doesnt help me understand how i should go about implementing the solutions ive seen online, plus i cant find any video tutorials on the subject. If someone could provide me with a solution and a despription of how it works and how should i use it, would be very helpful.

This is the fragment that loads first when the app is opened:

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_home, container, false);


        ImageButton workButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.work_button);
        ImageButton calendarButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_button);

        workButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Work()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
```

- Here your `NavigationView` must be be present in your activity with id of `nav_view`
- The `position` here says which number of item in drawer must be  checked/selected.
  Your Home Fragment (**edited**):

  ```
  public class Home extends Fragment {

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_home, container, false);

      ImageButton workButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.work_button);
      ImageButton calendarButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_button);

      workButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Work()).addToBackStack(null).commit

              NavigationView navigationView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
              navigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);

          }
      });
  ```

  }

Comment: Sorry for asking dumb questions but im a total begginer. Should this be inside the MainActivity or the Home fragment?

Comment: You said you need to change whenever a button is clicked inside fragment. SO do it inside fragment

Comment: That makes sense. But i have 2 errors, "Cannot resolve symbol 'navigationView'" and "Cannot resolve symbol 'position'"

Comment: Have you declared NavigationView inside activity's xml layout?

Comment: In the the Home Fragment xml? I didnt.

Comment: Not in Home Fragment.

Comment: In the activity_main.xml i do have declared a NavigationView.